# Email.send fails with latest 0.9.4

Tags: email, meteor

bkmorris/Meteor-Email-Test works good with no update.
'smtp://localhost:25' no problem using postfix

after update to 0.9.4 Email.send fails
ReferenceError: email is not defined

Comment: Could you post a code snippet or the app source code? What version were you using before?

Comment: https://github.com/bkmorris/Meteor-Email-Test nothing changed just meteor update

Comment: Meteor.startup(function () {

 process.env.MAIL_URL = 'smtp://localhost:25' ;

  Meteor.methods({
    sendEmail: function (to, from, subject, text) {
      check([to, from, subject, text], [String]);

      // Let other method calls from the same client start running,
      // without waiting for the email sending to complete.
      this.unblock();

      Email.send({
        to: to,
        from: from,
        subject: subject,
        text: text
      });
    }
  });

Comment: errorClass: Method not found [404] testapp.js?3f652f06853d15fb617effda8537f2cca9b9af99:23
Error invoking Method 'sendEmail': Internal server error [500]

Comment: I20141027-20:17:23.778(-7)?     at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
I20141027-20:17:23.779(-7)?     at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:895:19)
I20141027-20:18:01.791(-7)? Exception while invoking method 'sendEmail' Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
I20141027-20:18:01.792(-7)?     at Object.Future.wait (/home/mark/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.34.yzi65y++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-

Comment: the github version is .8 ? upgrade appeared to fail with a mailgun snmp setting. However after several attempts 'smtp://localhost:25' did work.

Answer (score 0):

process.env.MAIL_URL = 'smtp://localhost:25' ;

meteor upgrade 
does work